# Map plot incomplete when using rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I have some data that I'd like to plot with rworldmap. Normally this works well. But I can't figure out why it's not plotting all the data when it says it's going to. Particularly it's not plotting data for the US.

I've got some data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fp7O2TRH5Blar56SqdRdcPh8Mb1Vb0pc/view?usp=sharing

And I'm running this code:

```
mergedData = readRDS("sampleData.rds")
changeHeatMapPalette = c('#D7191D', '#FDAE61', '#FFFFBF', '#ABD9E9', '#2C7BB6')
mapData = joinCountryData2Map(mergedData, joinCode="ISO2", nameJoinColumn="country", mapResolution = "high")
mapCountryData(mapData, nameColumnToPlot="change", mapTitle="", catMethod = "diverging", colourPalette = changeHeatMapPalette, numCats = 90, borderCol = "grey70")
```

But then I'm getting this map:
[image: map plot]

Notice how the US has no data. But it's definitely in the sample data. And it's only excluding one country, which is not the US.

```
108 codes from your data successfully matched countries in the map
1 codes from your data failed to match with a country code in the map
     failedCodes
[1,] "GF"       
143 codes from the map weren't represented in your data
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please add `library('rworldmap')` so the code will be fully reproducible

Comment: or even `library(rworldxtra)`, which you seem to be using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you set the `colourPalette` and `numCats` parameters in a quite random fashion.

From your data we know exactly how many categories we have, and it can be counted with: `length(table(mapData$change)` and you need exactly that many colors (if you provide less then `mapCountData` will interpolate them with a warning).

Having said that, one solution of your problem is this

```
mapCountryData(mapData, 
  nameColumnToPlot="change", 
  mapTitle="", 
  catMethod = "diverging", 
  colourPalette = brewer.pal(library(RColorBrewer), 'RdYlBu'), 
  numCats = length(table(mapData$change)), 
  borderCol = "grey70")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I didn’t realize numCats would need to be exact. I had thought they were just setting a histogram in the background of sorts and just putting all the data in that number of buckets. And while I was getting the interpolation warning for the colors, that *seemed* fine to just let it interpolate.